# Is there a way to call a function once a View Controller leaves the view stack?

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller

ViewDidDisapear and ViewWillDisappear are still called if another View Controller is above the (say, for example, you push a view controller on top of it). Is there a function that is only called once the view controller is removed from the navigation stack? Adding a function to the back button works, but what if the user decides to to the edge pan gesture to dismiss the view? Is there an action that accounts for both events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I can think of few ways to do this off the top of my head

One option would be to add some code to a dealloc method of the UIViewController.

If you don't expect the view controller controller to get deallocated when it leaves the stack you can also set a UINavigationControllerDelegate for the UINavigationController and define

```
func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController,
                               didShow viewController: UIViewController,
                               animated: Bool) {
  guard let poppedViewController =
        navigationController.transitionCoordinator?.viewController(forKey: .from) 
  <Do something with the popped VC>
```